# How to define common bindings for all components of a same module in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

For example :

#### form.js

```
angular.module('myForm', []);
```

#### form-input-component.js

```
angular.module('myForm').component('inputField', {
  template: '<input type="text"></input>',
  bindings: {
    fieldName: '@',
    value: '='
  },
  controller: function () { }
});
```

#### form-select-component.js

```
angular.module('myForm').component('inputSelect', {
  template: '<select></select>',
  bindings: {
    fieldName: '@',
    value: '='
  },
  controller: function () { }
});
```

Is it possible to define all common bindings in `form.js`?

Comment: do you receive any error if you try?

Comment: Yes, I get $injector.modulerr errors on missing `fieldName` transclude value

Answer (score 0):

With js yes, but not with angular syntax:

**form.js**

```
var commonBindings = {
   fieldName: '@',
   value: '='
}
angular.module('myForm', []);
```

**form-input-component.js**

```
angular.module('myForm').component('inputField', {
  template: '<input type="text"></input>',
  bindings: commonBindings,
  controller: function () { }
});
```

but you need to ensure that `commonBindings` var has a global scope (so do not define with IIFE) and components that need more bindings must copy the value ad add properties before the component definition:

```
var customBindings = angular.copy(commonBindings);
customBindings.customVariable = "@";
```